# Migrate php code from mysql_ to mysqli_

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a php code which is created for php 5.3 I need to use it with php 5.6 so need to convert the code from mysql_ to myspli_. Please help.

content of database.php

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_username = "usr12345"; 
$db_password = "pass12345"; 
$database = "db12345";
?>
```

Php content

```
// If database.php does not exist then print error
if (!include("database.php")) die("database.php could not be loaded!");
if ($db_host == "" || !isset($db_host)) die("please reinstall this panel");
//MySQL Verbindung wird getestet
$connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die ("database could not be connected");
$db = mysql_select_db($database) or die ("database could not be selected");
// Logincheck
session_start();
// Language File check on DB
$captcha_sql = mysql_query("SELECT language FROM settings WHERE id='0'");
$language_setting = mysql_result($captcha_sql,0);
// Check if Language-file exists and include, else load English
if (file_exists("./pages/messages/".$language_setting.".php")) {
    $language_setting = $language_setting;
}
else {
    $errors[] = "<h2>The language file could not be found, English is the default language!</h2>";
    $language_setting = "english";
}   
include "./pages/messages/".$language_setting.".php";
// Get variable for include
if (!isset($_GET['include'])) { 
    $include_php = "main";
}
else {  
    $include_php = $_GET['include'];    
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a code conversion request.

Answer (score 0):

this should work fine:

```
function mysqli_result($res,$row=0,$col=0){ 
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($res); 
    if ($numrows && $row <= ($numrows-1) && $row >=0){
        mysqli_data_seek($res,$row);
        $resrow = (is_numeric($col)) ? mysqli_fetch_row($res) : mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        if (isset($resrow[$col])){
            return $resrow[$col];
        }
    }
    return false;
}



// If database.php does not exist then print error
    if (!include("database.php")) die("database.php could not be loaded!");
    if ($db_host == "" || !isset($db_host)) die("please reinstall this panel");
    //MySQL Verbindung wird getestet
    $connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$database) or die ("database could not be connected");
    //$db = mysql_select_db($database) or die ("database could not be selected");
    // Logincheck
    session_start();
    // Language File check on DB
    $captcha_sql = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT language FROM settings WHERE id='0'");
    $language_setting = mysqli_result($captcha_sql,0);
    // Check if Language-file exists and include, else load English
    if (file_exists("./pages/messages/".$language_setting.".php")) {
        $language_setting = $language_setting;
    }
    else {
        $errors[] = "<h2>The language file could not be found, English is the default language!</h2>";
        $language_setting = "english";
    }   
    include "./pages/messages/".$language_setting.".php";
    // Get variable for include
    if (!isset($_GET['include'])) { 
        $include_php = "main";
    }
    else {  
        $include_php = $_GET['include'];    
    }
```